# How to use one variable in different class

Tags: java, class, variables, paint

So I'm new to programming in Java and I have some problems with the program I'm trying to write. I have to create some kind of Paint. I created 2 classes, in the first one I've written a method that gives every button (pencil, line etc) its number and title:

```
public JButton whichButton(Stringg title, final int number){
  JButton theBut = new JButton();
  theBut.setText(title);
  theBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         currentAction = number;
         System.out.println("actionNum:" + number);
      }
   });
   return theBut;
}
```

Now there's a problem. I want to use this "number" in second class to know which figure my program should paint. I added all the mouseListeners, MouseMotionListeners etc in constructor of the second class and then used "if and else" commands which are comparing chosen number with the number of specific figure. 
To "get" the right number I wrote a method in second class:

```
public int gentNumber(){
   return numer;
}
```

And because the panel that my figures should be painted on (drawingpanel) is an object of the second class I tried to add this to the  method "whichButton":

```
currentAction=drawingpanel.getNumber();
```

But it doesn't work.
I know that what I've written might be a bit chaotic, but as I said, I've been programming in Java for only a month and I'm not an expert in this. 
I would be very grateful for any help how to make this work!

Answer (score 0):

We don't have too many code to fully solve your problem but as I understand you just need to have in your second class instance a reference to the first class instance to be able to retrieve the `currentAction`. Something that should looks like:

```
class SecondClass extends JPanel { // probably some paintable component like this
    private FirstClass firstClassInstance;

    public SecondClass(FirstClass fci) { firstClassInstance = fci; }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { // what is called on repaint request
      switch (firstClassInstance.getCurrentAction()) {
      case 1: // draw rectangle
      case 2: // draw circle
      // etc.
    }
}
```